# Is there a way to output keystokes in Python or Java?

Tags: java, python, keyboard, output

Say I have an array of ints from 0-5. Is there a way to make each of these numbers map to a specific key press and can I set the amount of time for which the key is pressed in either java or python?

Comment: The answer is "yes."

Comment: Yes, there is. Did you do any research on this on your own? Within about 30 seconds, I was able to find some examples by googling. Without any actual effort shown, it sounds like you're just asking us to do your research/coding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in Java with java.awt.Robot

```
int keyToPress = ...;
int timeToPress = ...;

Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(keyToPress);
Thread.sleep(timeToPress);
r.keyRelease(keyToPress);
```

Comment: @tnw The Internet is hateful enough without me coming down on those who maybe haven't done enough to deserve our help. Just my opinion on life/the Internet